# Qt QThread thread call

Tags: c++, qt, oop, qthread

I am trying to use Qt's built in Qthread to run a thread that runs a series of GPIO pins. I have confirmed that the pins are running, the problem is implementing Qthread.

This is my code in the header file:

```
class Runtest : public QThread
{
public:
    explicit Runtest(const QString& mark) : mark_(mark) {}

    void run();
private:
    QString mark_;
};
```

My .cpp code:

```
void Runtest::run()
{
    wiringPiSetup();        //enable gpio library
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);     //gpio pin 4 enabled

   int x=0;
    while(x<1000)
    {
        x++;
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);    //gpio output high
        delay(5);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);     //gpio output low
        delay(5);
    }
}
```

and I want to call the object from the main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //setup_gpio();
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    Runtest go1;
    go1.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This isn't working, the error I am receiving is `no matching constructer for initialization of 'Runtest'` on the line `Runtest go1`
 I am not very experienced with object oriented coding yet, what am i doing wrong? How can I get `Runtest::run()` to run?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to a define a constructor with the name of `Writer`, but your class is named `Runtest`?

Comment: I don't know the GPIO library but I suspect that they are asynchronous   so control needs to return to an event loop in order to communicate, whereas you've got your thread tied up in a while loop. As an experiment, replace the `delay(x)` lines with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`.

Comment: Another thing, you only need to subclass `QThread` when you're doing something major. For simple tasks, consider the `QRunnable` class in conjunction with the `QThreadPool` class. This frees you up to focus on solving your problem and lets Qt worry about the threading. Also, it optimises your thread usage with regards to your CPU. If there are too many threads running, `QRunnable`s are queued until a previous job is completed.

Comment: Apart from there being a typo in the constructor declaration (it's called `Runtest`, not `Writer`), your code works correctly. Try putting a `qDebug() << "here";` in the body of `run()`. Most likely your gpio code is broken. The problem is *not* in the code that you show.

Comment: wiringPiSetup() has a return value. Check it for errors. And one question... how do you know that it does not work? How did you check? You are aware that delay(5) creates a 5ms delay which means e.g. you can not see the blinking of a LED?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @Silicomancer, I have tested the wiringPi library with a procedural c++ code, and it ran fine.

Comment: Anyway you should check the return value. *Never* ignore return values. Still there is my question: how do you check if it works?

Comment: Okay, I will do so, I have ran a stepper motor off of the GPIO output.

Comment: I have changed the constructor error from `Writer` to `Runtest`, the problem I am having now is: `No matching constructor for initialization of 'Runtest'` on the line `Runtest go1;`

Comment: Your `Runtest` constructor is expecting a `QString` as a parameter. You're not giving it one.

Comment: So the issue was determined, as I stated it was not the WiringPi library, it was the constructor named `Writer` and the expectation of a `QString` that had to be removed, if one of you who commented, would like to add the answer below, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your constructor like this:

```
explicit Runtest(const QString& mark) : mark_(mark) {}
```

It is expecting a `QString` as a parameter. But you are initializing your object like this:

```
Runtest go1;
```

You're not passing a `QString` to the constructor.

You should initialize it something like this:

```
Runtest go1("My string");
```